# How can i get all outputs of the last transformer encoder in bert pretrained model and not just the cls token output?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, text-classification, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm using pytorch and this is the model from huggingface transformers [link](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification):

```
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertForSequenceClassification
bert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased",
                                                     num_labels=int(data['class'].nunique()),
                                                     output_attentions=False,
                                                     output_hidden_states=False)
```

and in the forward function I'm building, I'm calling `x1, x2 = self.bert(sent_id, attention_mask=mask)`
Now, as far as I know, x2 is the cls output(which is the output of the first transformer encoder) but yet again, I don't think I understand the output of the model.
but I want the output of all the 12 last transformer encoders.
How can I do that in pytorch ?

Comment: This seems to not be pure pytorch. Are you refferring to the class in Huggingface Transformers? If so - plase make that clear in the question and provide the appropriate tag. https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification

Comment: Well I'm using pytorch hence the tag, and yes I'm referring to the class in Huggingface Transformers and i edited the question and added a link.

Comment: Sweet. Then I think your question is good and you can have my upvote. Unfortunately, Im not familiar with huggingface so I can't help you more.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, if you want to look into the outputs of all the layer, you should use `BertModel` and not `BertForSequenceClassification`. Because, `BertForSequenceClassification` is inherited from `BertModel` and adds a linear layer on top of the BERT model.

```
from transformers import BertModel
my_bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

### Add your code to map the model to device, data to device, and obtain input_ids and mask

sequence_output, pooled_output = my_bert_model(ids, attention_mask=mask)

# sequence_output has the following shape: (batch_size, sequence_length, 768), which contains output for all tokens in the last layer of the BERT model.
```

`sequence_output` contains output for all tokens in the last layer of the BERT model.

In order to obtain the outputs of all the transformer encoder layers, you can use the following:

```
my_bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
sequence_output, pooled_output, all_layer_output = model(ids, attention_mask=mask, output_hidden_states=True)
```

`all_layer_output` is a output tuple containing the outputs embeddings layer + outputs of all the layer. Each element in the tuple will have a shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, 768)`

Hence, to get the sequence of outputs at layer-5, you can use `all_layer_output[5]`. As, `all_layer_output[0]` contains outputs of the embeddings.

Comment: Hi Ashwin, maybe you could add `output_hidden_states=True` to your question and explain it a bit because the OP also wanted to know how he can output the output of each encoding layer.

Comment: Hi Cronoik, if I am not wring, the OP asks for the output of last layer and not each layer. May be OP can edit the question to add more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

detailed in the doc: https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertModel.

```
from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig

config = BertConfig.from_pretrained("xxx", output_hidden_states=True)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("xxx", config=config)

outputs = model(inputs)
print(len(outputs))  # 3

hidden_states = outputs[2]
print(len(hidden_states))  # 13

embedding_output = hidden_states[0]
attention_hidden_states = hidden_states[1:]
```